# Could not update nested object value using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update one single value from mongoDB document but its not updating anything. Let me to explain my code below.

```
const Product = new Schema({

    StoreCode: { type: String},
    ProductName : { type: String},
    CouponRules: [
          {
            CouponId: String, 
            CouponCode: String, 
            CouponValue: Number, 
            Description: String,
            SKU: String,
            Category: String,
            CouponType: String,
            CouponCount: Number, 
            StartDate: String,
            EndDate: String, 
            IsActive: String
          }
        ]
})
```

The above is my mongoose schema.

```
const productsCollection = loadMongoModel(PRODUCTS_COLLECTION);
        data.tableInfo.forEach(element => {
            let arr = [];
            const coupon = {
                CouponId: Coupon._id,
                CouponCode: data.data.CouponCode, 
                CouponValue: data.data.CouponValue, 
                Description: data.data.CouponDescription,
                SKU: '',
                Category: data.data.CouponCategory,
                CouponType: data.data.Type,
                CouponCount: data.data.Count, 
                StartDate: data.data.StartDate,
                EndDate: data.data.EndDate, 
                IsActive: data.data.IsActive
            }
            arr.push(coupon);
            if (element.checked == true) {
                const objectId = isObjectID(element._id);
                const pro = {
                    CouponRules : arr
                }
                const result = productsCollection.update( { _id : objectId}, { $set : pro }, { multi:true });

            }
        });
```

Here I am trying to add only the `CouponRules` values with one new row but unable to do this.

Comment: No, same issue.

Comment: Check the answer below, because you should not use `pro`, instead use `coupon` directly. Let me know if it works.

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? Are you entirely replacing `CouponRules` with new array or just pushing a new object to existing `CouponRules` array ? Also can you do `productsCollection.find( { _id : objectId})` & let me know if you're getting the doc back !!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$push` to add a new row to the *CouponRules* array and instead of `pro` use the variable `coupon` directly.

```js
const result = productsCollection.update(
    { _id : objectId}, {$push: { CouponRules : coupon }}, { multi:true }
);
```

Comment: It creates also same issue.

Comment: Try changing this `const objectId = isObjectID(element._id);` to `const objectId = ObjectID(element._id);`